# Программа которая строит график функции выводит пустое окно координат

Tags: python, matplotlib

Мной была написана программа ниже, но не могу найти ошибку. Программа должна строить функцию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, но просто выводит окно координат.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 5000)

print ('Введите х')
x = float(input())
print ('Введите n')
n = float(input())
z = float()
z = 0
y = float()
if n > z:
    y = pow(x, 1 / n)
elif n < z:
    y = x ** (1 / n)
elif n == z:
    print ('Ошибка, n/0')
print (y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8, 6))
ax.set_title("Графики функции y=x^1/n", fontsize = 16)
ax.set_xlabel("x", fontsize = 14)
ax.set_ylabel("y", fontsize = 14)
ax.grid(which = "major", linewidth = 1.2)
ax.grid(which = "minor", linestyle = "--", color = "black", linewidth = 0.5)
ax.plot(x, y, label = "y = {}^1/{}".format(x, n))
ax.legend()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
ax.tick_params(which = 'major', length = 10, width = 2)
ax.tick_params(which = 'minor', length = 5, width = 1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Должна строить функцию, но на самом деле делает что?

Comment: закоментируйте строки: `print ('Введите х')` и `x=float(input())` и все заработает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что после ввода `x=float(input())` - весь график превращается в единственную точку.

Если вы хотите построить нормальный график, то `x` должен представлять из себя вектор последовательных значений, например как у вас выше в коде: `x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 5000)` и тогда `y` тоже будет векторо значений. Имея два вектора `x` и `y` можно легко построить график функции:

```
n = 4
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 5000)
y = x**(1/n)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(x, y, label=f"y = x^1/{n}")
ax.legend()
ax.grid()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]